# Webform Multistep - conditional wizard skipping

Tags: 8, webforms

Is there a way to create a multistep form in Webform and add conditional logic somehow that, based on submission values, certain steps are skipped?

Example, I have a 10 step wizard Webform. Based on certain answers in the first 3 steps, steps 4-6 may be skipped, or in some cases, sent from step 3 to the final step. In other cases, the user would go through every single step (normal).

I tried looking around for examples but didn't come across anything concrete. [I did find this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2850813), but I am not sure if that is still current?

Webform version: 6.x

Answer (score 1):

Wizard pages support conditional logic which can be used to skip steps as needed.

Comment: I see - so you mean on the Conditions tab with states?

Answer (score -2):

I'm getting frustrated because I have the same problem - conditional logic controlling a wizard page doesn't work. I see this question over and over online but respondents just keep saying it works, but nobody explains what we are all doing wrong.

Presumably if so many people get stuck on this, there is something counter-intuitive about how we should be setting it up. Please help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135795)